# Python: dereferencing weakproxy

Tags: python, weak-references

Is there any way to get the original object from a weakproxy pointed to it? eg is there the inverse to `weakref.proxy()`?

A simplified example(python2.7):

```
import weakref

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, other):
        self.other = weakref.proxy(other)

class Other(object):
    pass

others = [Other() for i in xrange(3)]

my_list = [C(others[i % len(others)]) for i in xrange(10)]
```

I need to get the list of unique `other` members from `my_list`. The way I prefer for such tasks
is to use `set`:

```
unique_others = {x.other for x in my_list}
```

Unfortunately this throws `TypeError: unhashable type: 'weakproxy'`

I have managed to solve the specific problem in an imperative way(slow and dirty):

```
unique_others = []
for x in my_list:
    if x.other in unique_others:
        continue
    unique_others.append(x.other)
```

but the general problem noted in the caption is still active.
What if I have only `my_list` under control and `others` are burried in some lib and someone may delete them at any time, and I want to prevent the deletion by collecting **nonweak** refs in a list?

Or I may want to get the `repr()` of the object itself, not `<weakproxy at xx to Other at xx>` 
I guess there should be something like `weakref.unproxy` I'm not aware about.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old question but I was looking for an answer recently and came up with something. Like others said, there is no documented way to do it and looking at the implementation of weakproxy type confirms that there is no standard way to achieve this.

My solution uses the fact that all Python objects have a set of standard methods (like **__repr__**) and that bound method objects contain a reference to the instance (in **__self__** attribute).

Therefore, by dereferencing the proxy to get the method object, we can get a strong reference to the proxied object from the method object.

Example:

```
>>> def func():
...    pass
...
>>> weakfunc = weakref.proxy(func)
>>> f = weakfunc.__repr__.__self__
>>> f is func
True
```

Another nice thing is that it will work for strong references as well:

```
>>> func.__repr__.__self__ is func
True
```

So there's no need for type checks if either a proxy or a strong reference could be expected.

**Edit:**

I just noticed that this doesn't work for proxies of classes. This is not universal then.

Answer (score 10):

Basically there is something like `weakref.unproxy`, but it's just named `weakref.ref(x)()`.
The proxy object is only there for delegation and the implementation is rather shaky...

The `==` function doesn't work as you would expect it:

```
>>> weakref.proxy(object) == object
False
>>> weakref.proxy(object) == weakref.proxy(object)
True
>>> weakref.proxy(object).__eq__(object)
True
```

However, I see that you don't want to call `weakref.ref` objects all the time. A good working proxy with dereference support would be nice.

But at the moment, this is just not possible. If you look into python builtin source code you see, that you need something like [PyWeakref_GetObject](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a82fc1f366b4/Objects/weakrefobject.c#l866), but there is just no call to this method at all (And: it raises a `PyErr_BadInternalCall` if the argument is wrong, so it seems to be an internal function). [PyWeakref_GET_OBJECT](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a82fc1f366b4/Include/weakrefobject.h#l69) is used much more, but there is  no method in [weakref.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/weakref.py) that could be able to do that.

So, sorry to disappoint you, but you `weakref.proxy` is just not what most people would want for their use cases. You *can* however make your own `proxy` implementation. It isn't to hard. Just use `weakref.ref` internally and override `__getattr__`, `__repr__`, etc.

On a little sidenote on how PyCharm is able to produce the normal `repr` output (Because you mentioned that in a comment):

```
>>> class A(): pass
>>> a = A()
>>> weakref.proxy(a)
<weakproxy at 0x7fcf7885d470 to A at 0x1410990>
>>> weakref.proxy(a).__repr__()
'<__main__.A object at 0x1410990>'
>>> type( weakref.proxy(a))
<type 'weakproxy'>
```

As you can see, calling the original `__repr__` can really help!

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is an old question, but I've been bitten by it (so, there's no real 'unproxy' in the standard library) and wanted to share my solution...

The way I solved it to get the real instance was just creating a property which returned it (although I suggest using `weakref.ref` instead of a `weakref.proxy` as code should really check if it's still alive before accessing it instead of having to remember to catch an exception whenever any attribute is accessed).

Anyways, if you still **must** use a proxy, the code to get the real instance is:

```
import weakref

class MyClass(object):

    @property
    def real_self(self):
        return self

instance = MyClass()
proxied = weakref.proxy(instance)
assert proxied.real_self is instance
```

Comment: thanks for this, works like a charm ... and feels a lot less hacky than using something like `proxy.__repr__.__self__`)

Answer (score 3):

weakref.ref is hashable whereas weakref.proxy is not.  The API doesn't say anything about how you actually can get a handle on the object a proxy points to.  with weakref, it's easy, you can just call it.  As such, you can roll your own proxy-like class...Here's a *very* basic attemp:

```
import weakref
class C(object):
   def __init__(self,obj):
      self.object=weakref.ref(obj)
   def __getattr__(self,key):
      if(key == "object"): return object.__getattr__(self,"object")
      elif(key == "__init__"): return object.__getattr__(self,"__init__")
      else:
          obj=object.__getattr__(self,"object")() #Dereference the weakref
          return getattr(obj,key)

class Other(object):
   pass

others = [Other() for i in range(3)]

my_list = [C(others[i % len(others)]) for i in range(10)]

unique_list = {x.object for x in my_list}
```

Of course, now unique_list contains `ref`s, not `proxy`s which is fundamentally different...

Comment: The API doesn't but IDEs like PyCharm are able somehow to present the result of repr() in the watchlist window.

Comment: @robyschek Of course it *is* possible.  I'm sure you could hunt the code down somewhere in the standard library and figure out how proxy objects work...but if it's not documented in the API, you can't guarantee that it will be portable to other python implementations...